# Think Bayes - Chapter 7 Exercice 7.4

Tags: self-study, bayesian, bayes

I'm reading this book by Allen B. Downey and trying to do the exercises
http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-bayes/

I am a bit stuck at this one, 7.4. I tried looking for blogs and stuff like that where people would discuss the solutions, but couldn't find anything

> Suppose you are the manager of an apartment building with 100 light bulbs in common areas. It is your responsibility to replace light bulbs when they break.
>
> On January 1, all 100 bulbs are working. When you inspect them on February 1, you find 3 light bulbs out. If you come back on April 1, how many light bulbs do you expect to find broken?
>
> In the previous exercise, you could reasonably assume that an event is equally likely at any time. For light bulbs, the likelihood of failure depends on the age of the bulb. Specifically, old bulbs have an increasing failure rate due to evaporation of the filament.
>
> This problem is more open-ended than some; you will have to make modeling decisions. You might want to read about the Weibull distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). Or you might want to look around for information about light bulb survival curves.

The book takes a practical approach, but I'm a bit more comfortable with the theory first.

- $x$ is the number of lights that will go out after another 2 months (3 total)
- $data$ will be the information that there were 3 lights out after the first month
- $\lambda$ and $k$ are the parameter for the Weibull

So I got this far
$P(x|data)=\sum_{\Lambda,K}{P(x|\lambda, k)P(\lambda,k|data)}$

and

$P(\lambda,k|data)=\frac{P(data|\lambda,k)P(\lambda)P(k)}{\sum_{\Lambda,K}{P(data|\lambda, k)P(\lambda)P(k)}}$

I think the math is good, I'm just not sure how to use the data or even if I'm setting $x$ right. The Weibull is the time to failure. So how does having knowledge that 3 light bulbs went out in the first month help me in figuring out the parameters of the distribution? What if 6 went out? What if they were still all good? What if it was 3 out of 200?

I'm thinking that I should be looking for something more along the lines of
$P(time\ to\ failure < 3\ months|data)$

Any help would be appreciated. Or if anyone know of a place where we can find the solutions that would be perfect.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).